# Javascript For loop wont work

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This is my code:

```
<div class="div">
<div id="picture"><img src="news1.jpg" /></div>
<div id="picture1"><img src="news2.jpg" /></div>
<div id="picture2"><img src="news3.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var element = document.getElementById("picture")
var element1 = document.getElementById("picture1")
var element2 = document.getElementById("picture2")


var zdjecia = new Array("element", "element1", "element2");
    for(var i=0; i < zdjecia.Length; i++)
        {   
         zdjecia[i].style.opacity="1";
        }
</script>
```

Could You give me some advise why that loop wont work ?. If I will find a problem, i will add settimeout and setTimeInterval to this, but at this moment i Can't find where is a problem with that loop.

Comment: You're trying to add style to strings, style only applies to DOM elements.

Comment: I am also using CSS. In css all pictures have opacity equal 0. And when page is loaded, the picture should appear, but they wont, and thats what i'am trying undesrtand why they wont appear.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for answer !. Is there a different way to do that ?

Comment: Different from what's in the answers?

Comment: Out of curiousity, does "zdjecia" translate more directly to photographs, pictures, or images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The others have shown you the two coding mistakes you made (wrong capitalization on `.length` and using strings instead of direct variable references), but I'd suggest this change to your code:

```
var items = ["picture", "picture1", "picture2"];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById(items[i]).style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of adding the elements as strings, add the elements as they are

```
var zdjecia = new Array(element, element1, element2);
```

and the length property should be accessed with [`zdjecia.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: Many thanks for any answer, but there is still problem with that. That code simply wont work :/

Answer (score 0):

**A Cleaner Approach**

```
<div class="div">
  <div class="picture"><img src="news1.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="picture"><img src="news2.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="picture"><img src="news3.jpg" /></div>
</div>

<script>
  var zdjecia = document.getElementsByClassName('picture');
  for(var i = 0; i < zdjecia.length; i++) {
    zdjecia[i].style.opacity = '1';
  }
</script>
```

**Here's what's wrong with your code**

You need to loop through the actual DOM elements, rather than strings with the same variable names `var zdjecia = new Array(element, element1, element2);`.

Also, JavaScript is case sensitive, and you've accidentally capitalized `length`. `zdjecia.Length` should be `zdjecia.length`.

```
[1, 2, 3].Length // => undefined
[1, 2, 3].length // => 3
```

Also, it's preferable to use JavaScript's array literal (the square brace form) to instantiating a new array:

```
var zdjecia = [element, element1, element2];
```

JavaScript's array literal is more predictable than direct instantiation. Consider the following:

```
new Array(2, 1) // => [2, 1]
new Array(2)    // => [undefined, undefined]
```

Reserve the direct use of `new Array()` for preallocating space in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
var zdjecia = new Array(element, element1, element2);  //Array of objects, not strings
for(var i=0; i < zdjecia.length; i++)        //Use .length instead of .Length
    {   
     zdjecia[i].style.opacity="1";
    }
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have a few minor errors. First, you're adding the elements as strings, not as the elements themselves. Second, you capitalized 'length' in your for loop. Don't do that.

```
var zdjecia = new Array(element, element1, element2);

for(var i=0; i < zdjecia.length; i++){   
 zdjecia[i].style.opacity="1";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for any answer, but there is still problem with that. That code simply wont work :/